# Are all the solutions produced?

Tags: equation-solving

Here is a very strong and impressive result of the `Reduce` command.

```
Reduce[a^2 + b^2 == 841*(a*b + 1), {a, b}, PositiveIntegers]
```

performs
`(a == 24389 && b == 29)`
and 6 infinite series of the solutions, one of these is

> `(C[1] \[Element] Integers && C[1] >= 0 &&  a == (1/1414554)(-(24389/ 2) (-707277 (297410399 - 353640 Sqrt[707277])^C[1] +  841 Sqrt[707277] (297410399 - 353640 Sqrt[707277])^C[1] -  707277 (297410399 + 353640 Sqrt[707277])^C[1] -  841 Sqrt[707277] (297410399 + 353640 Sqrt[707277])^C[1]) -  20511033/ 2 (-841 (297410399 - 353640 Sqrt[707277])^C[1] +  Sqrt[707277] (297410399 - 353640 Sqrt[707277])^C[1] -  841 (297410399 + 353640 Sqrt[707277])^C[1] -  Sqrt[707277] (297410399 + 353640 Sqrt[707277])^C[1])) &&  b == -(1/1414554) 29 (-707277 (297410399 - 353640 Sqrt[707277])^C[1] +  841 Sqrt[707277] (297410399 - 353640 Sqrt[707277])^C[1] -  707277 (297410399 + 353640 Sqrt[707277])^C[1] -  841 Sqrt[707277] (297410399 + 353640 Sqrt[707277])^C[1]))`

I checked one of the solutions

```
a^2 + b^2 - 841*(a*b + 1) /. {a -> 10260556177351789709,  b -> 12200440766273760}
```

> `0`

The same result is produced by `Solve`.  I find it great. BTW, Maple 2021 fails with it.

This is problem 16 from [Kvant 2020, # 10, p. 42](https://kvant.ras.ru/pdf/2020/2020-10.pdf) (in Russian).
Its solution is given in p. 60 ibid . However, no explicit formulas are presented there, but only an algorithm
to obtain all the solutions in `PositiveIntegers`.

My questions are: are all the solutions  produced by `Reduce`/`Solve`? how to establish it? I hope the answer to the first question is yes.

Comment: "are all the solutions produced by Reduce/Solve?" I think this question belongs on [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Roman: Thank you for the interest to the question. I am going to ask it there too. Maybe, the developers of the `Reduce` command would find time to shed a light on my question. I think it's in their best interest.

Comment: @Roman: Thanks for the idea. [Cross-asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4066730/are-all-the-solutions-produced-by-mathematica) in MSE.

Comment: Why not just translate the Russian to English?  Surely there are free resources on the web for doing that.

Comment: @Dominic: This is not a problem. The problem consists in different approaches done by Mathematica (series of explicit solutions) and by hand (an algorithm). I don't see how to compare the ones.

Comment: Here is a start of the translation of the algorithm: The solutions $a,b$ (provided $a\le b$) are
those and only those pairs of numbers $(a,b)$ that for
each $n \in \mathbb N $ are calculated by the formulas:$a_n=b_{n-1}, b_n=k^2b_{n-1}-a_{n-1},a_0=0, \,b_0=k$, here $k=29$.

Comment: At the moment I see three votes to close this question, but only @Roman  grounded it.

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

sol = Thread[{a, 
    b} -> ({a[n], b[n]} /. 
     RSolve[{a[n] == b[n - 1], b[n] == 29^2*b[n - 1] - a[n - 1], a[0] == 0, 
        b[0] == 29}, {a, b}, n][[1]])]

(* {a -> -((29 (2 (841 + Sqrt[707277]))^-n (4^n - (841 + Sqrt[707277])^(2 n)))/
   Sqrt[707277]), b -> 29 ChebyshevU[n, 841/2]} *)
```

For integer `n` this satisfies the original equation

```
Assuming[n ∈ Integers,
 a^2 + b^2 == 841*(a*b + 1) /. sol // FullSimplify]

(* True *)
```

For an alternate representation:

```
sol2 = sol // FunctionExpand // ComplexExpand // FullSimplify

(* {a -> -((58 Sinh[n Log[2/(841 + Sqrt[707277])]])/Sqrt[707277]), 
 b -> (58 Sinh[(1 + n) Log[1/2 (841 + Sqrt[707277])]])/Sqrt[707277]} *)
```

Verifying this representation,

```
Assuming[n ∈ Integers,
 a^2 + b^2 - 841*(a*b + 1) /. sol2 // FullSimplify // ComplexExpand // 
  FullSimplify]

(* 0 *)
```

Looking at values for specific values of `n`

```
Table[{n, sol}, {n, -5, 5}] // RootReduce // Grid
```

[image]

From the symmetry, an alternative representation is

```
sol3 = {a -> -29*ChebyshevU[-(n + 1), 841/2],
   b -> 29*ChebyshevU[n, 841/2]};
```

Verifying,

```
Assuming[n ∈ Integers,
 a^2 + b^2 == 841*(a*b + 1) /. sol3 // FullSimplify]

(* True *)
```

Comment: The equation is treated over `PositiveIntegers`, not over `Integers` as you did.

Comment: @user64494 - While your interest is positive integer values for `n`, the solutions are shown to be valid for all integer values of `n`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a start of the translation of the algorithm: The solutions $a,b$ (provided $a\le b$) are those and only those pairs of numbers $(a,b)$ that for each $n\in \mathbb N$ are calculated by the formulas:$a_n=b_{n−1},\,b_n=k^2b_{n−1}− a_{n−1},a_0=0,b_0=k$, here $ k=29$.

Next, the `RSolve` command cracks it:

```
RSolve[{a[n] == b[n - 1], b[n] == 29^2*b[n - 1] - a[n - 1], a[0] == 0,
b[0] == 29}, {a, b}, n]
```

> `{{a -> Function[{n}, -(( 29 (2 (841 + Sqrt[707277]))^-n (4^n - (841 + Sqrt[707277])^( 2 n)))/Sqrt[707277])],  b -> Function[{n}, 29 ChebyshevU[n, 841/2]]}}`

It remains to compare this result with the result of `Reduce`

Comment: `29 ChebyshevU[5, 841/2]` produces `12200440766273760`.

Comment: Indeed, `29 {ChebyshevU[3 i + 2, 841/2], ChebyshevU[3 i + 3, 841/2]}` is one of the solution branches for $i\in\mathbb{N}_0$.